# How to measure effect of treatment in a group not chosen randomly?

Tags: inference

I have a group of 3.5 thousand people. Let them have a characteristic C that is a known indicator of whether or not they will take action A. I intentionally select the 500 people with lowest C and apply a treatment designed to induce A. How would I measure the effectiveness of the treatment?

Comment: if the group is  instead chosen randomly, what method would you have used

Comment: if the group was chosen randomly I would have used a t-test